# Spring Boot/JPA not persisting with service layer

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot along with Spring Data JPA.
I'm stucking in an odd scenario when saving a new entity.

Unsing method from extended CrudRepository class, all works as expected. 
If I inject via @Autowired the CrudRepository interface in my service layer, the method still works, but nothing is persisted on db.
The returned object from 'save' method seems ok, since I get an always increasing ID value.

Suggestions?
Cheers 
FB

Comment: Please show repository class, and domain object

Answer (score 0):

check whether we are populating the data properly in your bean and check it before passing to save method of spring data jpa